# Как добавить telegram бота в канал?

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

Есть телеграм-бот у которого в настройках включено разрешение добавлять его в группы (эта же настройка вроде как отвечает и за разрешение добавлять бота в каналы). Есть публичный телеграм-канал. Из под администратора канала пытаюсь добавить бота в админы. Но поиском почему-то бот не ищется. И в какую-либо группу тоже бота добавить не получается по той же причине. Бот по @NameMyBot не ищется. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: недостаточно деталей, поскольку проблема видимо в том КАК именно производится поиск

Comment: такая же проблема! не видет в списке со всех устройств

Comment: Каналу надо скормить ключ бота.